# Drupal using views with CCK custom fields

Tags: drupal, cck, custom-fields

I've got a Drupal site which uses a custom field for a certain type of node (`person_id`) which corresponds to a particular user. I want to create a view so that when logged in, a user can see a list of nodes 'tagged' with their `person_id`. I've got the view working fine, with a url of `my-library/username` but replacing `username` with a different username shows a list of all nodes tagged with that user. What I want to do is stop users changing the URL and seeing other users' tagged nodes. How can I do this? Is there somewhere where I can dictate that the only valid argument for this page is the one that corresponds with the current logged in user's username?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how you have setup your view, which gives some different options to solve this. A way that should work would be to set the default argument be the logged users id/username and remove the argument from the url.

Alternatively you could create your own filter which requires some work with the views API, but gives more control.

Answer (score 2):

person_id = uid?
In this case, add argument with user:uid, then in Validation options select PHP Code, read comment of this field carefully:

> Enter PHP code that returns TRUE or
>   FALSE. No return is the same as FALSE,
>   so be SURE to return something if you
>   do not want to declare the argument
>   invalid. Do not use . The
>   argument to validate will be
>   "$argument" and the view will be
>   "$view". You may change the argument
>   by setting "$handler->argument".

Add this code:

```
global $user;
$account = user_load('name'=>arg(1));
$handler->argument = $user->uid;
return $account->uid == $user->uid;
```